# Prevent C# code in MVC View execution on load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a C# MVC project setup. In my view, I have C# code using Razor in a JavaScript function. I'm calling the JavaScript function only on a click event.

However, when the page loads, this function is getting called leading to the C# code being executed which I did not expect. Is there a way I can prevent the execution on load and execute only when the function gets called?

Here's my code:

```
<a id="id1" href="#">Link</a>

$("#id1").click(function () {
    customFunction();
});

function customFunction() {
    @using System;         
    @using System.Web.Configuration; 
    @using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    @{
       // C# code
     }
}
```

`customFunction()` is getting executed when the page loads.

Comment: It is not being executed on 'page load'. It is being executed on the server before its even sent to the view. C# code is server side code and your browser knows nothing about it. The only way for you browser to execute code on the server in response to a client side event (clicking a button) is to use ajax to call the server method.

Comment: thats weird that a click function would get called on page load. put a console.log('test'); before the customFunction();  to double check some old code isn't cached and also to confirm the click function is getting called..

Answer (score 2):

The c# code is run when the page is generated. Basically it constructs the web page that goes to the browser, so no c# code is run on the browser.

I usually limit the razor code to building the page structure or getting information from models.